# JQuery.sort by data option and class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a problem with the javascript sort function.
The following function sorts the items in the wrapper by data-price attribute descending.

**HTML Part:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item" data-price="1"></div>
    <div class="item" data-price="2"class="blacklisted"></div>
    <div class="item" data-price="3"></div>
    <div class="item" data-price="4" class="blacklisted"></div>
</div>
```

**JQuery Part:**

```
    var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
    $wrapper.find('.item').sort(function (a, b) {
        return -a.getAttribute('data-price') - -b.getAttribute('data-price');
    }).appendTo($wrapper);
```

Now I want to change to JQuery part that it sort by data-price and .blacklisted

*current response*

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item" data-price="4" class="blacklisted"></div>
    <div class="item" data-price="3"></div>
    <div class="item" data-price="2"class="blacklisted"></div>
    <div class="item" data-price="1"></div>
</div>
```

*wished response:*

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item" data-price="3"></div>
    <div class="item" data-price="1"></div>
    <div class="item" data-price="4" class="blacklisted"></div>
    <div class="item" data-price="2" class="blacklisted"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: For everybody who's looking for a nice filter solution check out this! https://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element should not have two `class` attributes. You can chain `.filter(".blacklisted")` then call `.appendTo()`

```js
var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
$wrapper.find('.item').sort(function(a, b) {
  return +a.getAttribute('data-price') > +b.getAttribute('data-price') ? -1 : 1;
})
.appendTo($wrapper)
.filter(".blacklisted")
.appendTo($wrapper);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item" data-price="1">price</div>
  <div class="item blacklisted" data-price="2">blacklisted</div>
  <div class="item" data-price="3">price</div>
  <div class="item blacklisted" data-price="4">blacklisted</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why shouldn't have an element two class attributes?

Comment: How does JavaScript know which attribute is applicable? If an element can have two `class` attributes, why should element not have two `id` attributes?

Comment: but you can tell me where the difference between the answer above and yours is?

Comment: Utilizing `.filter()` after initial sort. Either approach should return same result

Comment: okay, thank you too but in your solution data-price isn't sorted correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly note that the `div` elements in your HTML have two `class` attributes which is invalid. You need to join them in to one.

To achieve what you require you can check whether or not the elements have the `blacklisted` class and then move them up/down appropriately. If neither have the class you can then sort them by the `data-price`, as you are now. Try this:

```js
var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
$wrapper.find('.item').sort(function(a, b) {
  if ($(a).hasClass('blacklisted') && !$(b).hasClass('blacklisted'))
    return 1;

  if ($(b).hasClass('blacklisted') && !$(a).hasClass('blacklisted'))
    return -1;

  return -a.getAttribute('data-price') - -b.getAttribute('data-price');
}).appendTo($wrapper);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item" data-price="1">1</div>
  <div class="item blacklisted" data-price="2">2b</div>
  <div class="item" data-price="3">3</div>
  <div class="item blacklisted" data-price="4">4b</div>
</div>
```